# Real time graph - error with ArrayList conversion

Tags: java, arraylist, javafx, graph, real-time

I am currently using XYChart to create a graph in java I do so using the following code:

```
    stage.setTitle("Emotion Analyser");

    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();

    xAxis.setLabel("Utterances");

    final LineChart<String,Number> lineChart = 
            new LineChart<String,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);

    lineChart.setTitle("Emotion Analysis");

    XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
    series1.setName("Happy");

    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("1st", 23));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2nd", 14));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("3rd", 15));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("4th", 24));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("5th", 34));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("6th", 36));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("7th", 22));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("8th", 45));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("9th", 43));
    series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("10th", 17)); 

    XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
    series2.setName("sad");
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("1st", 33));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2nd", 34));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("3rd", 25));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("4th", 44));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("5th", 39));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("6th", 16));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("7th", 55));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("8th", 54));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("9th", 48));
    series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("10th", 27)); 

    XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
    series3.setName("Shocked");

    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("1st", 44));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("2nd", 35));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("3rd", 36));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("4th", 33));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("5th", 31));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("6th", 26));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("7th", 22));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("8th", 25));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("9th", 43));
    series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("10th", 44)); 

    Scene scene  = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);       
    lineChart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
```

image: [image]
This is when you want to add them manually when you no all of the data... however I am trying to create a real-time updating graph, which doesn't know how many lines it is going to have each time it is run, so one run it might have 2 lines on the graph, second time run it could have 6.

So I wanted to somehow use an ArrayList like:

[image: arraylist]

and do the same as what the previous,

I tried doing:

```
list.get(0).setName("Happyq");
```

but that didn't work

Error:

```
Executing /
```

Comment: What does "that didn't work" mean? What actually happens?

Comment: @James_D when i added list.get(0).setName("Happyq"); , i add list.get(0) to lineChart.getData().addAll(list.get(0),series1, series2, series3); so that it is dsplayed in the graph, when i run it i get loads of errors like "Exception in Application start method"

Comment: [Edit] the question to include the complete [stack trace](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450).

Comment: @James_D i added an image of the error !

Comment: Please add it as text.

Comment: @James_D added it as text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error

```
Caused by java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

indicates that you are trying to access the first element of the list (for example, by calling `list.get(0)`) when the list is empty (`Size: 0`).

The stack trace tells you this is happening at line 42 of `GraphTry1.java`.

For more information on reading and interpreting a stack trace, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3988788/2775450).